# Export describe.by (package psych) as csv file in R

Tags: r, psych, describe.by

Does anyone know how to export describe.by statistics to csv in R? I get this message:

```
estatistica <- describe.by(pag,list(pag$Jogo)

  write.table(estatistica,file="H:/Myfile.csv",sep=",")
  "Erro em as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""by"" to a data.frame"
```

Since its such a general question, a general example would do.

```
        Jogo  Pais  Numero
          A  Canada    1
          B  Canada    2
          C  Canada    1
          D  Canada    4
          A  Brazyl    6
          B  Brazyl    7
          A  France    1
          B  France    1
          C  France    2
          D  France    3
```

Comment: He.  Welcome to SO.  It's the general norm to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for those trying to help.  That means we can run your example precisely.  Also please use code tags to indicate code.  Use `\`` marks for in text and the `{}` button to show code blocks.

Comment: I thought about giving a example, but its such a general question, I didnt thought I had to. But I can do any example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Function `describeBy()` (this should be used instead of `descrive.by()` that is deprecated) produces list of data frame and therefore can't be written to file with `write.table()`.

```
library(psych)    
estatistica <- describeBy(pag,list(pag$Jogo))
estatistica

: A
       var n mean   sd median trimmed  mad min max range skew kurtosis   se
Jogo*    1 3 1.00 0.00      1    1.00 0.00   1   1     0  NaN      NaN 0.00
Pais*    2 3 2.00 1.00      2    2.00 1.48   1   3     2 0.00    -2.33 0.58
Numero   3 3 2.67 2.89      1    2.67 0.00   1   6     5 0.38    -2.33 1.67
-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
: B
       var n mean   sd median trimmed  mad min max range skew kurtosis   se
Jogo*    1 3 2.00 0.00      2    2.00 0.00   2   2     0  NaN      NaN 0.00
Pais*    2 3 2.00 1.00      2    2.00 1.48   1   3     2 0.00    -2.33 0.58
Numero   3 3 3.33 3.21      2    3.33 1.48   1   7     6 0.34    -2.33 1.86
```

To solve this problem one way would be to put all list elements into one data frame with `do.call()` and `rbind()` and then write to file. This will make data frame where group names will be added before original variable names.

```
estatistica2<-do.call("rbind",estatistica)
estatistica2

         var n mean   sd median trimmed  mad min max range skew kurtosis   se
A.Jogo*    1 3 1.00 0.00    1.0    1.00 0.00   1   1     0  NaN      NaN 0.00
A.Pais*    2 3 2.00 1.00    2.0    2.00 1.48   1   3     2 0.00    -2.33 0.58
A.Numero   3 3 2.67 2.89    1.0    2.67 0.00   1   6     5 0.38    -2.33 1.67
B.Jogo*    1 3 2.00 0.00    2.0    2.00 0.00   2   2     0  NaN      NaN 0.00
B.Pais*    2 3 2.00 1.00    2.0    2.00 1.48   1   3     2 0.00    -2.33 0.58
B.Numero   3 3 3.33 3.21    2.0    3.33 1.48   1   7     6 0.34    -2.33 1.86
C.Jogo*    1 2 3.00 0.00    3.0    3.00 0.00   3   3     0  NaN      NaN 0.00
C.Pais*    2 2 2.50 0.71    2.5    2.50 0.74   2   3     1 0.00    -2.75 0.50
C.Numero   3 2 1.50 0.71    1.5    1.50 0.74   1   2     1 0.00    -2.75 0.50
D.Jogo*    1 2 4.00 0.00    4.0    4.00 0.00   4   4     0  NaN      NaN 0.00
D.Pais*    2 2 2.50 0.71    2.5    2.50 0.74   2   3     1 0.00    -2.75 0.50
D.Numero   3 2 3.50 0.71    3.5    3.50 0.74   3   4     1 0.00    -2.75 0.50
```

Comment: Horray for the old and venerable do.call(rbind, ...) strategy.

Comment: If you use the matrix option of describeBy, you will get a data frame that can be written with the write.table command.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, there is an option in describeBy that creates matrix form output to just this.
Using the original data,

describeBy(pag,pag$Jogo,mat=TRUE)

```
        item group1 var n     mean        sd median  trimmed    mad min max range      skew  kurtosis        se
Jogo*1     1      A   1 3 1.000000 0.0000000    1.0 1.000000 0.0000   1   1     0          NaN       NaN 0.0000000
Jogo*2     2      B   1 3 2.000000 0.0000000    2.0 2.000000 0.0000   2   2     0       NaN       NaN 0.0000000
Jogo*3     3      C   1 2 3.000000 0.0000000    3.0 3.000000 0.0000   3   3     0       NaN       NaN 0.0000000
Jogo*4     4      D   1 2 4.000000 0.0000000    4.0 4.000000 0.0000   4   4     0       NaN       NaN 0.0000000
Pais*1     5      A   2 3 2.000000 1.0000000    2.0 2.000000 1.4826   1   3     2 0.0000000 -2.333333 0.5773503
Pais*2     6      B   2 3 2.000000 1.0000000    2.0 2.000000 1.4826   1   3     2 0.0000000 -2.333333 0.5773503
Pais*3     7      C   2 2 2.500000 0.7071068    2.5 2.500000 0.7413   2   3     1 0.0000000 -2.750000 0.5000000
Pais*4     8      D   2 2 2.500000 0.7071068    2.5 2.500000 0.7413   2   3     1 0.0000000 -2.750000 0.5000000
Numero1    9      A   3 3 2.666667 2.8867513    1.0 2.666667 0.0000   1   6     5 0.3849002 -2.333333 1.6666667
Numero2   10      B   3 3 3.333333 3.2145503    2.0 3.333333 1.4826   1   7     6 0.3434206 -2.333333 1.8559215
Numero3   11      C   3 2 1.500000 0.7071068    1.5 1.500000 0.7413   1   2     1 0.0000000 -2.750000 0.5000000
Numero4   12      D   3 2 3.500000 0.7071068    3.5 3.500000 0.7413   3   4     1 0.0000000 -2.750000 0.5000000
```

> 

Unfortunately, the current version does not have the rounded output that describeBy does normally.  I have fixed this in Version 1.3.6 (about to be released).

Bill

Comment: Well, it wasn't version 1.3.6, but 1.3.10 has this feature. (The digits option in describeBy)

Comment: This is a bit old but can't quite find a better place to ask this - getting a "subscript out of bounds" error when grouping by two variables and `mat=TRUE`. (Works ok if `mat=TRUE` is removed.) Using psych version 1.8.12. `Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, var, group + 1, value = dim.names[[group]][[groupi]]) : 
  subscript out of bounds`

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example of this problem (perhaps using dput() for your data.  I can not reproduce this error.  I just tried `des <- describeBy(sat.act,group=c("gender","education"),mat=TRUE)` and it works.
'

Comment: @WilliamRevelle when I convert it to a matrix, it pairs the variables together, as opposed to separating one group of variables from another. Is there a way to correct this?